# Symfony 2 multiple form in same page Submition

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

I try to make a simple login-register on the same page.

- One form for register
- One form for login.

I manage to render 2 forms on the page that I want, but if I try to submit the registration form it gives me a message that the other form cannot be empty.

Before I tried to merge the pages my registrations worked without any problem  my login not(just created the form) my code:

`AccountController.php` the file that renders to the template.

The form creation has implemented in `RegistrationType.php` and in `LoginType.php`

```
<?php
namespace Spyros\MapBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Spyros\MapBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType;
use Spyros\MapBundle\Form\Type\LoginType;
use Spyros\MapBundle\Form\Model\Registration;
use Spyros\MapBundle\Form\Model\Login;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $registration = new Registration();
        $form1 = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType() , $registration, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_create') ,
        ));

        $login = new Login();
        $form2 = $this->createForm(new LoginType() , $login, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_create') ,
        ));

        return $this->render('SpyrosMapBundle:Account:register.html.twig', array(
            'form1' => $form1->createView() ,
            'form2' => $form2->createView()
        ));

    }

    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $form1 = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType() , new Registration());

        $form1 > handleRequest($request);

        if ($form1->isValid())
        {
            $registration = $form1->getData();

            $em->persist($registration->getUser());
            $em->flush();
            echo "<p>hi</p>";
        }
        return $this->render('SpyrosMapBundle:Account:register.html.twig', array(
            'form1' => $form1->createView()
        ));

    }

}
```

register.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'SpyrosMapBundle::rightform.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form1 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form2 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<body>
   <section class="container">
      <section class="row">
         <section class="col col-lg-9">
            {{ form_start(form2 , {'attr': {'class': 'form-inline'}} )}}
            {{ form_row(form2.user.email)}}
            {{ form_row(form2.user.plainPassword)}}
            <div id="inline">
               {{ form_row(form2.Login) }}
            </div>
         </section>
         <section class="col col-lg-3">
            {{ form(form1) }}
         </section>
      </section>
   </section>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

My View page:

[image: my view page]

How can i submit my registration form(form1) without form2 give me a message to fill its fields.

Comment: Don't use the same action="" for each form, but make a dedicated controller for each form and make sure that neither tries to handle the other.

Comment: If i make 2 dedicated controller for each form how i will renter them in the same page?

Comment: How do you mean? You want to be able to fill out and send both forms at the same time?

Comment: i want  no to submit them in same time, only to see both form and to be able to submit one of them. the dedicated controller will be only for submition? no for creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that it is your browser that is complaining about blank fields?  One of the less amusing things about Symfony 2 forms is that, by default, all fields are required.  This is implemented by setting a required attribute on the input element itself.  The browser then process the attribute.

Couple of ways to get around this.  Set required = false when creating the element:

```
     $builder->add('name','text', array(
        'required' => false,  /***** Make it optional *****/
        'label'    => 'Your Name',
        'trim'     => true,
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlankConstraint($constraintOptions),
        ),
        'attr' => array('size' => 30),
    ));
```

You can also pass this in to your form options when creating the form so everything is optional by default.

You can also add a simple novalidate attribute to the form element itself in your twig template.

By the way, as @Spiro suggested, if you are using the built in security system then you will need to submit each form to a different url.  Otherwise the security system will intercept your create user requests.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required

Comment: thx a lot my friend :) try first working, but i will do the secont cauuse of security system